# How to switch on pop-up (PDF) by using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to switch on popup window which has the pdf file by using python selenium package but unable to switch.

I have tried this:

```
parent_h = browser.current_window_handle
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//i[@class = 'fa fa-certificate']")[i].click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//object[@data]")

handles = browser.window_handles # before the pop-up window closes
handles.remove(parent_h)

browser.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
```

link: https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/searchlist/search?MenuID=1069

Fill the project name 'Hirandani' than click on search and than click on 'View Certificate' icon, will get the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to switch on the pdf frame by using the tag method.

Answer (score 0):

Pop up is not different window. So no handler or switching is required. It is embedded in html. If you are just trying to get the pdf data then use this.

```
pdf_data = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('object').get_attribute('data')
```

To close pdf pop up

```
browser.find_element_by_id('button.ui-button.ui-widget').click()
```

Comment: get encoded data base64, also tried to decode but not getting